# Invalid CSRF Token Spring 4 MVC while trying to upload

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, multipart

I am trying to upload a file with a web application using Spring MVC 4 but I am getting an error:

> Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

Spring version:

> Spring Version 4.1.7.RELEASE
>
> Spring Security 4.0.1.RELEASE

Code:

> web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <display-name>FATCA Web Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-web-servlet.xml         
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>  

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

> spring-web-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:webapp.properties" />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.opessoftware" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

> Settings.jsp

```
<form:form method="POST" action="uploadFile.html"
                            enctype="multipart/form-data" security="none">
                            <table style="width: 100%" border="1">
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="1" style="text-align: left"><input
                                        type="file" name="file" style="width: 100%;" /></td>
                                    <td colspan="1" style="text-align: left"><input
                                        type="submit" value=<spring:message code="uploadSettings" /> />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </form:form>
```

Post request payload contents after submitting a file called `test.txt` that contains the string "Test":

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------83935555814334632461054528816
Content-Length: 368

-----------------------------83935555814334632461054528816
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Test
-----------------------------83935555814334632461054528816
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_csrf"

41f3dc0a-b97f-4dac-bc49-21e02be53818
-----------------------------83935555814334632461054528816--
```

Comment: CSRF protection is on by default in Spring Security 4.x.  Since you have not posted your Spring Security configuration, I am going to assume that you have not switched it off (otherwise you wouldn't have received the said error).  The tricky thing is that in a multipart request, each part is considered individually and hence must contain the CSRF token.  This can be a pain to implement so there are workarounds.  See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397939/spring-security-3-2-csrf-support-for-multipart-requests) for a potential workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this by following the general advice in the second point of [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25269365/107158) to [*Spring Security 3.2, CSRF and multipart requests*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185578/spring-security-3-2-csrf-and-multipart-requests), but using Spring Security 4.0.1.RELEASE instead of version 3.2.

#### Change 1

Updated the Web application from [Servlet API 2.4](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr154/index.html) to [Servlet API 3.0](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
          version="3.0">
....
</web-app>
```

#### Change 2

Using Java based configuration, created a [`StandardServletMultipartResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/support/StandardServletMultipartResolver.html) which uses the multipart handling of Servlet 3.0 and does not require [`commons-fileupload`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.3.1).  Note that the original implementation neglected to explicitly create any multipart resolver, though it did include dependency `commons-fileupload` in the Maven project.

```
@Configuration
public class WebApplicationConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }
}
```

#### Change 3

Added "multipart-config" to the [`DispatcherServlet`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html):

In `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-web</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <multipart-config>
        <location>/tmp</location>
        <max-file-size>1000000</max-file-size>
        <max-request-size>1000000</max-request-size>
        <file-size-threshold>10000</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
</servlet>
```

Using Java:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
    super(SecurityConfiguration.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
    final XmlWebApplicationContext appContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
    appContext.setConfigLocation("/WEB-INF/spring-web-servlet.xml");

    final ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher",
        new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
    registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    registration.addMapping("/");
    registration.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement("", 1000000, 1000000, 100000));
    }
}
```

#### Change 4

Removed dependency `commons-fileupload` from the Maven project.